# Unity3D ScriptableObject with UnityEvent not saving event parameter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inspector

I have a ScriptableObject container which I show on a custom editor as a node of a graph. The container also has a custom inspector, with another ScriptableObject called Action on it, besides other fields.

My problem is: The Action has a UnityEvent. When I set the object and the method to be called by the event, it persists with no problem, but when I put some parameter to the method, the parameter do not persists. Only if after changing the parameter, I change the method to other with the same parameter and them change it back. I guess by doing that I force some kind of serialization.

How this structure is used:

[image: Custom editor on unity: It shows some nodes and the fileds on inspector respective to one of the nodes.]

EDIT:

That is the code of the my Action class that has the UnityEvent:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class UnityEventAction : ToolKitAction {
public UnityEvent onInteractionTrigged;

public override void Execute( GameObject dialogController ){
    onInteractionTrigged.Invoke();
}
```

This is the ScriptableObject it extends:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class ToolKitAction:  { public virtual void Execute(GameObject 
gameObject) { } 
}
```

The class that contains this object:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Interaction {

private enum State{ ACTIVE, INACTIVE }; 
private State state = State.INACTIVE;

public int interactionId;
[SerializeField]
public ToolKitAction tkAction;
...
}
```

A ScriptableObject that works only as a container for the Interaction, which represents the node of the editor.

```
public class InteractionContainer: ScriptableObject{
public Interaction interaction;
}
```

**The class of the Custom Inspector for this container:**

[Custom Inspector](https://bitbucket.org/ceci_costa/adventure-toolkit/src/93965f0206abbacac8b4d15edd01b39b8ce89606/Assets/Editor/InteractionContainerInspector.cs?at=master)

**The class of the Custom Editor that creates the node editor:**

[Custom Node Editor](https://bitbucket.org/ceci_costa/adventure-toolkit/src/93965f0206abbacac8b4d15edd01b39b8ce89606/Assets/Editor/InteractionNodesEditor.cs?at=master)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, can you please share some code so anyone can understand you problem.

Comment: Thanks! 
Added some code parts that may help understand the problem.

Comment: Looks much better now. Thanks